# How to adapt object to use in md-select of vue-material?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I'm using Vue-Material. It doesn't support the passing of objects inside the value of the option.

This is the [link](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1458) to Github issue about it with some advice how to make this work.

What I can not do is implement it to the structure of my object.

I want to have the first select with options of `value2` of all items.
And then in the second select, I want to have all `values1` of selected `value2`.

[Here what I have so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2joyw7w8j)

I hope that someone can help me with it.

What works without Vue Material:

I just bind to the value of option the selected object. And when @change on select reassign in my data something like `this.innerGroup = this.selectedGroup.value1` and then just loop over `this.innerGroup` in `v-for`

Comment: Here is one way to do it. https://codesandbox.io/s/xjypwlxn1o

Comment: Yes that works! Although I didn't think about another issue if I'm passing `id` and not object - what If I want to use my objects later in another method. Right now in my `model` selected id`s are stored.

Comment: Well I suppose you could just create two computed values that always return the selected objects using the model ids. It's unfortunate that the library you are using doesn't support objects; that's very un Vue like.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out how to get my objects. But there is another issue - the second select doesn't get updated if you choose something else from the first one. Here is updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/3kpkw3z6pm
So if you choose the first value from the first select and the first from the second it is fine. But if you choose after that in the first select another value - option of the first one still visible in the second.

Comment: Ok, nevermind - just added @event to md-select to clear the second value every time. Thank you for the help!